# Android convert string to date changes the whole datetime

Tags: java, android, calendar

Why are the outputs are not the same?

```
   Date currentTrueSystemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuwait"));
    String newConvertedDate = sdf.format(currentTrueSystemDate.getTime());
    System.out.println(newConvertedDate);
    try {
        Date newConvertedDate2 = sdf.parse(newConvertedDate);
        System.out.println(newConvertedDate2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

output:

```
 I/System.out: 27-Sep-2018 09:16:52
 I/System.out: Thu Sep 27 07:16:52 GMT+01:00 2018
```

The reason I am converting "newConvertedDate" from a string to date because I want to use the `.before` and `.after` functions on it. I don't understand why parsing a string into date changes the time?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why parsing a string into date changes the time?

`format()` will convert a date(which has no timezone, it is the number of milliseconds passed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) into a string representation in the timezone you specified, in this case, Kuwait.

So the first time you get a String in Kuwait timezone and just print it. This is just a string with no time zone info. But the time is Kuwait time.

Then you convert the string into a date using parse() which is assuming that the date is in Kuwait time as sdf instance is same. Now this string is converted to a date and System.out.println prints it in your local timezone.

Thing to note is that both time are same just different timezones.

If you want same times, you need to create a new instance of SimpleDateFormat and pass the date string to it. So that it would assume that this is the local time zone date and parse to return a date  which when printed will again give the same value. However note that this date isn’t the same as previous one, just the time is same.

Do like this

```
Date currentTrueSystemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuwait"));
        String newConvertedDate = sdf.format(currentTrueSystemDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(newConvertedDate);
        try {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Date newConvertedDate2 = sdf.parse(newConvertedDate);
            System.out.println(newConvertedDate2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Could you please complete your answer. There is nothing after do this...

Comment: @Aboodnet Sorry, last time the rest of the portion didn't got submitted by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If by “changes the time” you mean the point in time, formatting and parsing does not change that.

First you format the time using a formatter that uses Kuwait time (Arabia Standard Time, equal to UTC+03:00). We see that when tis happened, the time in Kuwait was 09:16:52.

Next you print a `Date` object that is (close to) equal to the first one. `System.out.println` implicitly calls `newConvertedDate2.toString` to find out what to print. `Date.toString` uses your JVM’s default time zone — GMT+01:00 — to render the string to print. When the time in Kuwait is 09:16:52, it is just 07:16:52 at UTC+01:00. So you are really getting the same time again.

Other tips:

- The date and time classes you are using — `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` — are long outdated and the former in particluar notoriously troublesome. Instead of using those consider adding the ThreeTenABP library to you Android project so you may use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with, and among other things much clearer about time zones.
- GMT+01:00 is a funny time zone setting for your JVM. You’d probably be happier with a true time zone like Europe/London, for example.
- There’s a bug in your format pattern string: Lowercase `hh` is for hour with AM or PM from 01 through 12. You need uppercase `HH` for hour of day from 00 through 23.
- When I said “close to” equal, it’s just because in formatting and parsing you are losing the milliseconds of the second since your format doesn’t include these. So there may be a difference of up to 999 milliseconds between the two times. Other than this difference you are getting nothing out of formatting your `Date` into a `String` and parsing it back into a `Date`. You may just as well use `.before` and `.after` on `currentTrueSystemDate`.

### Links

- [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/) on Jon Skeet’s coding blog
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes.

Here is a brief but nonsensical example of going from current moment in a time zone to text in your desired format without zone/offset, and then back again to a moment in a time zone.

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                                                   // Represent a date and time-of-day without a time zone or offset-from-UTC. **NOT* a moment, but represents potential moments along a range of about 26-27 hours.
    ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kuwait" ) )                    // Represents a moment, a point on the timeline, a date and time-of-day with an assigned time zone.
    .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US ) )  // Generate a `String` with text representing the value of our `ZonedDateTime` object.
    ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US )  // Specify `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms used in localizing such as parsing the name of the month.
)                                                                      // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kuwait" ) )                                  // Assign a time zone to the `LocalDateTime` to determine a moment, to generate a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Also, I suspect you meant `HH` for 24-hour clock rather than lowercase `hh` for 12-hour clock.

First, get the current moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kuwait" ); // FYI, `Asia/Kuwait` is an alias of `Asia/Riyadh`.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2018-09-27T22:41:45.314343+03:00[Asia/Kuwait]

Next, generate text in your desired format to represent the value of our `ZonedDateTime`. Important: Notice that your string format is *incomplete*, lacking the fraction-of-second and lacking any indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

Define a formatting pattern. Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:
  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Get a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US );
```

Generate text.

```
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

> 27-Sep-2018 22:41:45

Going back the other direction is trickier because your desired format for this string lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Such a string does *not* represent a moment. Taken at face value, it could be any of many *potential* moments along a range of 26-27 hours (the range of time zones around the globe). I know, and you know, that the string is *intended* to be a moment in the time zone `Asia/Kuwait` with an offset-from-UTC of three hours ahead. But the string does not *literally* say that.

So we must first parse the string as a `LocalDateTime`, having no zone/offset.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( output , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-09-27T22:41:45

Then we inject the intended zone to determine a moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ldt.atZone( z );
```

> zdt2.toString(): 2018-09-27T22:41:45+03:00[Asia/Kuwait]

To close the circle, let’s compare our second [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object with the first. To do fairly, we must [lop off](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) the fraction-of-second omitted from your desired text format.

```
boolean sameZdt = zdt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).isEqual( zdt2 );
```

> true

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Date currentTrueSystemDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kuwait"));
    String newConvertedDate = sdf.format(currentTrueSystemDate.getTime());
    System.out.println(newConvertedDate);
    try {
        Date newConvertedDate2 = sdf.parse(newConvertedDate);
        System.out.println(newConvertedDate2);
        // Format the Date back to String here
        System.out.println(sdf.format(newConvertedDate2));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

output:
27-Sep-2018 10:03:41
Thu Sep 27 03:03:41 EDT 2018
27-Sep-2018 10:03:41